# Надо ли ставить союз Чтобы, если связь очевидна?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

*Лучший способ приблизиться к Богу — это тишина.*

Нужно ли вставить *чтобы* перед словом *приблизиться*
На мой взгляд и так всё понятно.

Comment: не нужно, с союзом смысл другой.

Comment: Есть способы достижения тишины, но сама тишина не способ, она — среда. Нужно править.

Answer (score 0):

1. Правильно:

*Лучший способ **приблизиться к Богу** — это тишина.*

***Способ (какой? дя чего?) приблизиться*** — инфинитив в функции несогласованного определения.  Тема есть **[у Розенталя (пункт 3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110)**: *Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с единственным **желанием — сделать** добро!*

Определение может не обособляться. **Желание делать** добро всегда было во мне.

2. Союз ***ЧТОБЫ*** со значением цели используется в подобных высказываниях, но там требуется **другая грамматика**:

*Нужно чаще находиться в тишине, **чтобы** стать ближе к Богу. СПП с **придаточным цели**.*

*Он хотел найти **такой** способ, **чтобы** всегда быть рядом с Богом.*  СПП с придаточным **определения и цели**.

*Я **хочу, чтобы** Бог всегда был в моем сердце.* СПП  с придаточным **изъяснительным**.